# sed insert file output between two keywords

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file which contain following content.

file.txt (**Note:** file content not static, its dynamic)

```
H 0 7 11 *
```

I want to insert them between two pattern  match using `sed` like following example,

infile content

```
...
...
<spec>H 0 7 11 *</spec>
...
...
```

I have tried following but i failed :( its putting below that line.

```
   $ sed '/<spec>/ r file.txt' infile
```

This is the output i am getting how do i put that between two match?

```
 <spec></spec>
   H 0 7 11 *
```

Comment: & that's the only line in file?

Comment: Why can't simply `read x < file.txt; echo "<spec>$x</spec>"`

Comment: @anishsane Yes, Thats all but it is not static content it would be change every time.

Comment: So the above comment using simple echo is OK? If yes, I can add that as answer then ;-)

Comment: What should happen if `file.txt` contains 3 lines of data?  1 line of output or 3 or 5?  Would it matter if `<spec>` was on one line, the data from `file.txt` on one or more other lines, and `</spec>` on another lines?  What about if `file.txt` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`sed 's#\(.*\)#<spec>\1</spec>#' input_file`

#### Update:

To do infile substitution you can use `-i` option. However, just be careful with that. You can use -i"bak" to make backup of the file before doing substitution.

`sed -i"bak" 's#\(.*\)#<spec>\1</spec>#' input_file`

#### Update 2:

```
awk '/\<spec\>/ { getline a < "dynamic.txt"; sub (/></, ">"a"<", $0); print ;next}1' infile
```

#### Update 3:

You can do a mix of bash and sed.

```
while read -r value; do  
    sed -i "s/></>$value</" infile ; 
done < dynamic.txt
```

Comment: Note: file.txt content not static, its dynamic

Comment: Also would it be good to add `-i` so that the file content is replaced?

Comment: where is infile in your syntax ?

Comment: @Satish Agreed. This is just something to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @fedorqui Yep, I would still recommend OP to use -i"bak" so that if he goes wrong he would still have his old file to play around with. :)

Comment: @Jaypal i want to insert that in infile

Comment: For the love of God don't do `cat file.txt| sed 's#...'` when you should be doing the (oh so obviously more meaningful) `sed 's#...#...#' file.txt`. Google "Useless Use of Cat" for more info.

Comment: @Jaypal - `not working` i guess you didn't understand my question

Comment: @Satish Updated. Sorry about that. This won't be in-file substitution. But you can redirect the output to another file.

Comment: Oh! boy i thought `sed` can do it in few option but look like there is no easy way out

Comment: @Satish Try the mix of `bash` and `sed`

Answer (score 0):

This will read the file just before sed gets executed:

```
sed -r  "s#(<spec>)(</spec>)#\\1$(<file.txt)\\2#" infile
```

I assume bash. If you use another shell replace `$(<file)` with `$(cat file)`

There will be trouble if the file content contains a `#`. You can change the `s###` delimiters, but you'll always have the same risk.